# PostgreSQL - how to loop over a parameter to make union of different queries of the same table

Tags: sql, postgresql, loops, for-loop, parameters

I need to count the number of events still occurring in a given year, provided these events started before the given year and ended after it. So, the query I'm using now is just a pile of unparametrized queries and I'd like to write it out with a loop on a parameter:

```
select
  count("starting_date" ) as "number_of_events" ,'2020' "year"
  from public.table_of_events
  where "starting_date" < '2020-01-01' and  ("closing_date" > '2020-12-31')
union all
select
  count("starting_date" ) as "number_of_events" ,'2019' "year"
  from public.table_of_events
  where "starting_date" < '2019-01-01' and  ("closing_date" > '2019-12-31')
union all
select
  count("starting_date" ) as "number_of_events" ,'2018' "year"
  from public.table_of_events
  where "starting_date" < '2018-01-01' and  ("closing_date" > '2018-12-31')
...
...
...
and so on for N years
```

So, I have ONE table that must be filtered according to one parameter that is both part of the `select` statement and the `where` clause

The general aspect of the "atomic" query is then

```
select
  count("starting_date" ) as "number_of_events" , **PARAMETER** "year"
  from public.table_of_events
  where "starting_date" < **PARAMETER**  and  ("closing_date" > **PARAMETER** )
union all
```

Can anyone help me put this in a more formal loop?

Thanks a lot, I hope I was clear enough.

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to want events that span *entire* years.  Perhaps a simple way is to generate the years, then use `join` and aggregate:

```
select gs.yyyy, count(e.starting_date)
from public.table_of_events e left join
     generate_series('2015-01-01'::date,
                     '2021-01-01'::date,
                     interval '1 year'
                    ) as gs(yyyy)
     on e.starting_date < gs.yyyy and
        e.closing_date >= gs.yyyy + interval '1 year'
group by gs.yyyy;
```

Comment: Great! Thanks a lot! This is actually a brilliant approach I've never thought of, and most important it works fine and fast.
By now I'm not making this the accepted answer just because I'd like to see other solutions that make actual use of a loop, so that I might reuse them in other occasions.